# HTTPS + Form Logon NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, authentication, nsurlconnection

I am using HTTPS to a form-logon page. 
When intercepting via

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge`
```

and extracting the Authentication Method used via

```
NSString *authenticationMethod = [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod];
```

I get the following

```
NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
```

But expected result should be

```
NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTMLForm
```

Is this due to using HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes

The purpose of the `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` authentication method is that the client can verify and trust that the server is actual the server it pretends to be.

The `NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTMLForm`is used to authenticate a user via a web form. The server sends a web form and requests user credentials. This authentication does not require to be send over SSL/TLS. But then the user's credentials will be send in the clear, which is a bad thing from a security point of view.

Client authentication is also part of the TLS protocol. In this case, you may receive a challenge whose method is `NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate`.

Notice, you may receive more than one authentication challenges.